# finding an odd digit in a number

Tags: python

So i have to make a program in python using a while loop. It goes like this: input an integer until it is 0.the program has to write out how many of inputed numbers has at least 1 odd digit in it.i don't know how to find odd digits in a number for which i don't know how many digits it has.i need this for school :/

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question. As it stands, your question doesn't fit the standards of this site.

Comment: Hint for one approach: [decimal representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_representation). How would you go about checking the first (rightmost) digit and then remove it?

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, the question you have asked is a little unclear. However, perhaps this is something like you are looking for?

```
odd_count = 0
user_number = None

# Ask for a user input, and check it is not equal to 0
while user_number != 0:
    user_number = int(input("Enter and integer (0 to quit): "))

    # Check for odd number by dividing by 2 and checking for a remainder
    if user_number % 2 != 0:
        odd_count += 1    # Add 1 to the odd number counter

print("There were {} odd numbers entered".format(odd_count))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
number=int(input())
i=0
odd_number_count=0
while number>0:
    for k in str(number):
        if int(k)%2==0:
            i=0
        else:
            i=i+1
    if i>>0:
        odd_number_count=odd_number_count+1
    number=int(input())
print(odd_number_count)
```

this is how i solved it